# Classification of irreducible complex representations of $\mathbb{H}_\mathbb{Z}^\times$ up to isomophism?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of the ring of integral quaternions.

**Question.** What is the classification of irreducible complex representations of $G$ up to isomorphism?

Comment: What do you mean precisely with integral quaternions? There are infinitely many $\mathbb{Q}$ forms of Hamiltons quaternion algebra and the unit group of a maximal order can vary.

Comment: @SteffenKionke I think OP means $\mathbb{H}_\mathbb{Z} = \{x = x_0 + x_1 i + x_2j + x_3 k \in \mathbb{H} : x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and taking the multiplicative group of that.

Comment: That's only a semigroup, there are only eight invertible elements in it, so some clarification of the OPs intention is needed.

Comment: And if integral quaternions means Hurwitz quaternions, then $G$ is a certain finite group with $24$ elements and the question is also rather trivial, or isn't it?